# Using pyinstaller for jupter_client's KernelManager not working

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pyinstaller, executable

I am using pyinstaller to make executable from my code. My code is running my python script multiple times and also not corrently for even one time as It is not receiving anything from get_iopub_msg function. My code is -

```
from jupyter_client import KernelManager
import re
import multiprocessing

def exec_code_in_kernel(kernel, code, full_traceback=False):
    kc = kernel.client()
    kc.start_channels()
    kc.execute(code)
    traceback = None
    output = None
    print("exec1")
    for i in range(3):
        print("exec2")
        try:
            msg = kc.get_iopub_msg(timeout=1)
        except:
            continue
        print(msg)
        if msg['msg_type'] == 'error':
            traceback = msg['content']['traceback']
            ansi_escape = re.compile(r'\x1B(?:[@-Z\\-_]|\[[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~])')
            
            if full_traceback:
                traceback = '\n'.join(traceback)
                traceback = ansi_escape.sub('', traceback)  # Remove ANSI escape sequences from traceback
            else:
                for line in traceback:
                    line = ansi_escape.sub('', line)  # Remove ANSI escape sequences from traceback
                    if re.search('.*(Error|Exception):', line):
                        traceback = line
                        break
                else:
                    traceback = 'Error'
        print("exec3")
        if (msg['msg_type'] == 'stream') and ("text" in msg['content'].keys()):
            output = msg['content']['text']
        print("exec4")
        if msg['msg_type'] == 'status' and msg['content']['execution_state'] == 'idle':
            break
    print("exec5")
    kc.stop_channels()
    print("exec6")
    return output, traceback

if __name__ == "__main__":
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    km = KernelManager(kernel_name="python3")
    km.start_kernel()
    output, traceback = exec_code_in_kernel(km, "print('hello')dsa")
    print("output", output)
    print("traceback", traceback)
    km.shutdown_kernel()
```

and I am building the exectutale via

```
pyinstaller temp.py \
--collect-all jupyter_client \
--collect-all zmq \
--collect-all traitlets \
--collect-all jupyter_core \
--collect-all tornado \
--collect-all dateutil \
--collect-all six \
--collect-all platformdirs \
--collect-all importlib_metadata \
--collect-all zipp \
--collect-all ipykernel_launcher \
--collect-all ipykernel \
--collect-all IPython \
--collect-all stack_data \
--collect-all executing \
--collect-all asttokens \
--collect-all pure_eval \
--collect-all pygments \
--collect-all pexpect \
--collect-all ptyprocess \
--collect-all typing_extensions \
--collect-all pickleshare \
--collect-all backcall \
--collect-all decorator \
--collect-all prompt_toolkit \
--collect-all wcwidth \
--collect-all comm \
--collect-all psutil \
--collect-all packaging \
--collect-all appnope
```

can you please help?

I have tried multiprocessing.freeze_support() and --noconsole option, but none of them hekped